# How to avoid dependency about at dependent objects

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, dependencies, dependency-management

I have a question about Spring Environment. If I have a controller and that controller has lots of services inside in it which is dependent each other and if I change something on that controller what I should do "less" by reducing amount of codes ? By that, how I will avoid dependency problem ? ,Hope my question is clear for you .

Thank you

Comment: Not quite clear to me actually. The question is how to reduce the dependencies? Avoiding touching too many places when something changes? Hard to tell without knowing the code and having deep knowledge about the requirements.

Comment: not quite clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents:

- Use autowired constructor injection as recommended by the Spring team. Doing this makes it very visible when your controller is getting bloated (see the next point)
- Have no more than 3 dependencies in the constructor as suggested by Bob Martin in his book Clean Code. If you have more, then your controller is probably violating the single responsibilty principle.
- If you want your controller to do more then you should probably put that functionality in a second controller!

A crude example:

```
    @RestController
    public class PetShopController {

    @Autowired private DogService dogService;
    @Autowired private CatService catService;
    @Autowired private MonkeyService monkeyService;
    @Autowired private FishService fishService;
// all three services above are dependent on the two below
    @Autowired private PetInsuranceService petInsuranceService;
    @Autowired private PetOwnerService petOwnerService; 

    //..and so on
    }
```

Change to:

```
@RestController
public class DogsController {

private DogService dogService;

//the insurance/owner services have been split into one service/pet type
private DogInsuranceService dogInsuranceService; 
private DogOwnerService dogOwnerService;

//I've used interfaces for types here
@Autowired DogsController(IPetService dogService,IInsuranceService dogInsuranceService, IOwnerService dogOwnerService) {
this.dogService = dogService;
this.dogInsuranceService = dogInsuranceService;
this.dogOwnerService = dogOwnerService;
}

//..and so on
// make similar controllers for other pets!!

}
```

I'd argue that it's not about reducing the amount of code, it's more about making sure each class has a single responsibility! Eg/ here Dogs do dog things like bark! Cats do cat things like meow!! As soon as you have a class with more than 3 deps/services that does both or more then that class needs to be split!!

Answer (score 0):

> controller has lots of services inside in it which is **dependent each
>   other**

That's a design smell right there, you might even get circular dependency problem with that kind of design. You may need to post your controller code here to get more help.